# Sorting Multideminsional arrays

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have the following JavaScript array,

```
var myArr= [{
    "key" : "Consumer Discretionary",
    "values" :[ 
               [1146369600000, 26.425199957521],
               [1138683600000, 27.38478809681],
               [1141102800000, 27.371377218208], 
               [1143781200000, 26.309915460827] 
              ]}, 
    {
     "key" : "Consumer Staples",
     "values" :[
                [1159588800000, 7.2800122043237], 
                [1141102800000, 7.1187787503354], 
                [1167541200000, 8.351887016482], 
                [1146369600000, 8.4156698763993]
              ]}
     ];
```

How can I sort the "values" of "key" Consumer Discretionary and then Consumer Staples in ascending order so it will look like

Consumer Discretionary :-

```
[1138683600000, 27.38478809681] 
[1141102800000, 27.371377218208] 
[1143781200000, 26.309915460827]
[1146369600000, 26.425199957521]
```

Any help on this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried. Do you know about the builtin `.sort()` method of array objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function valuePredicate(a,b){
    return a[0]!==b[0] ? a[0]-b[0] : a[1]-b[1];
}

for(var i=0; i < myArr.length;++i){
    myArr[i].values.sort(valuePredicate);
}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fVPBf/)

Comment: I spiced up the array a bit, like the following
"values" : [{ "x" : 0, "y" : 2.42}, {"x" : 1,"y" : 2.38}, {"x" : 2,"y" : 2.37}, {"x" : 3,"y" : 2.30}]}];

But could not manage to sort it with "x" , any idea why ??

Comment: @shabeer90 In that case,you need to use `return a.x!==b.x ? a.x-b.x : a.y-b.y;` ...

Comment: thanks again for this, i was trying return a.x[0]!==b.y[0] ? a.x[0]-b.y[0] : a.x[1]-b.y[1]; , i am still learning javascript so apologies for being stupid, any recommended books/anything i can read to get more practical exposure?

Comment: @shabeer90 I really do not know what book to suggest you. What I have learned,is from the forums(like SO),blogs and from my own practice :).